# On the height of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Which of the following inequalities hold for a ring $R$ and an ideal  $I\subset R$?

> $\operatorname{height}I\leq\dim R-\dim R/I$
>
> $\operatorname{height}I\geq\dim R-\dim R/I$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\dim R$ is finite.  Let $P$ be a prime containing $I$ such that $\dim R/I = \dim R/P$.  We then have

$$\operatorname{ht}I + \dim R/I = \operatorname{ht}I + \dim R/P\le \operatorname{ht}P + \dim R/P \le \dim R.$$

[Reference](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Height_of_an_ideal)

Answer (score 0):

I think to have it: suppose $\mathrm{height}\;I=n$ and $\mathrm{dim}\;R/I=m$ then we have a chain

> $\mathfrak{p}_0\subset\ldots\subset\mathfrak{p}_n\subset I\subset\mathfrak{p}_{n+1}\subset\ldots\subset\mathfrak{p}_{n+m}$

but in general $\mathrm{dim}\;R$ would be greater, so

> $\mathrm{height}\;I+\mathrm{dim}\;R/I\leq\mathrm{dim}\;R$ holds

Comment: This answer is wrong. If $\operatorname{ht}I=n$ we don't necessarily have a chain of prime ideals of length $n$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_0\subset\cdots\subset\mathfrak{p}_n\subset I$. Take, for instance, the ideal $I=4\mathbb Z$.